Excel Office Script
I'm not even sure if this is possible but I am trying to write an Office Script to copy the contents of one table and paste it to a new file and save it.  The script I'm using I got some help from ChatGPT:
    function copyTableDataToTemplateAndSave() {
  // Define the name of the source table
  let tableName = "Table1"; // Change "Table1" to the name of the table you want to copy

  // Get the source table
  let sourceTable = workbook.getTable(tableName);

  if (!sourceTable) {
    console.error("Table not found!");
    return;
  }

  // Get the range of the table
  let sourceRange = sourceTable.getRange();

  // Open the existing template workbook
  let templateWorkbook = ExcelScript.workbooks.open("path_to_your_template_file.xlsx");

  // Get the worksheet where you want to paste the data
  let targetWorksheet = templateWorkbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1"); // Change "Sheet1" to the actual sheet name in your template

  // Define the target range in the template worksheet where you want to paste the data
  let targetRange = targetWorksheet.getRange("A1"); // Change "A1" to the actual range where you want to paste the data

  // Copy the table data to the target range in the template worksheet
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all);

  // Save the template workbook as a new file
  templateWorkbook.saveAs("path_to_save_new_file.xlsx"); // Change "path_to_save_new_file.xlsx" to the desired file path and name

  // Close the template workbook
  templateWorkbook.close();
}

When I change everything to the specific details and try to run it I get these errors
See line 6, column 6: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.

See line 14, column 6: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.

See line 17, column 6: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.

See line 20, column 6: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.

See line 23, column 6: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.

I've tried to look online and I can't quite figure out what the issue is with the "variable" and some sites are suggesting it's impossible to do what I want.
Please help
Thanks

OfficeScript is different with VBA. It doesn't support open any workbook file. You need to use Power Automate.

Do you need to preserve formatting when copying the table over? If so, I'm not sure that can be done today through Power Automate and Office Scripts - but if not, I might be able to suggest a solution.

I’m open to any solution really - maintaining existing formatting isn’t essential :)

As a quick bit of background: Office Scripts can only operate on specific the workbook they're running in. So, to pass data between two workbooks, you'll likely need Power Automate. There are two ways you can do this:
1. Use basic Excel connector actions
You can create a flow that lists all rows present in the source table, then iteratively inserts each row into the destination table, like so:

In the "add row into a table" action, you'll need to expand the advanced parameters to specify the value for each column in the new row.
This only works if you want to add onto the destination table - if you want to overwrite the data already there, it becomes a little more complicated and I'd recommend the second solution instead.
2. Use two Office Scripts
You can create a flow that runs two scripts. First, we need a script to read and export data from the source table:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, tableName: string): string {
    // Get all values in the table
    return JSON.stringify(workbook.getTable(tableName).getRange().getValues());
}

Second, we need a script to take in this data and write it to the destination table:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, tableData: string, destinationTable: string) {
    let values: (string | number | boolean)[][] = JSON.parse(tableData);
    workbook.getTable(destinationTable).getRange().setValues(values);
}

Alternatively, if you want to copy the data to a non-table range, you should use the following as your second script:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, tableData: string, destinationSheet: string, destinationRange: string) {
  let values: (string | number | boolean)[][] = JSON.parse(tableData);
  workbook.getWorksheet(destinationSheet).getRange(destinationRange).setValues(values);
}

When you set up the "run script" actions in Power Automate, make sure to specify the right workbooks and parameters based on where you want to copy the data from/to.
Hopefully that helps - let me know if you have any questions!
